# How to hide the comment form label (not title)?

Tags: comments, entities

I have tried a number of different modules that claim to do this but none have worked, I have also tried changing the comment.tpl file, and I even tried using CSS "Display:none"; however nothing has worked. So how can I hide the "Comment" label on a comment form box? I am not talking about the comment title here, as this can be easily disabled in the content type settings. This is what I am talking about:
[image]

I originally thought that this could be done in the manage display settings, by setting the comment label to hidden. So I did this but it didn't change the label of the comment box:
[image]

So how can this be done? I simply want to hide the word "Comment" and the "*" after it of course.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with CSS. Looking at dev tools, I see that the label is called **edit-comment-body-und-0-value** (yours might be different). So what we need to do is, simply edit the CSS file and put in the line `label[for*="edit-comment-body-und-"] { display:none; }` and clear the cache at /admin/config/development/performance.

That's all there is to it.

K.

Comment: I have tried using CSS however it doesn't hide it unfortunately. The only way I have managed to get close with CSS is to use the "label" tag (since the Comment is a label) and setting it to display none, however this affects ALL labels which is not ideal. If it works for you, could you post a screenshot because as I said I cannot get it to work using CSS classes/ids. I am using D7 by the way.

Comment: @FrontEnd I tried again at my own end, and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that Kartagis, the problem though is that each comment box label uses a different label name. I've added a screenshot in my question showing the label name using Firebug. The problem is that the label name automatically adds "--#" at the end of the label name, so the first node comment box label will be "edit-comment-body-und-0-value", the next will be "edit-comment-body-und-0-value--1" then "edit-comment-body-und-0-value--2" and so on. This makes it impossible to use CSS because you have to add more CSS whenever a new node is created.

Comment: If I apply CSS to "edit-comment-body-und-0-value" it will only hide the first comment box's label and the rest of the label show. Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hmmm that didn't work for me. I tried:
label[for="edit-comment-body-und-*-value"]
and: label[for="edit-comment-body-und-0-value--*"] and neither hid any of the labels. I flushed the cache each time and tested it several times. It's not letting me add the asterisk in the comment, but basically I tried what you suggested and also I tried putting the asterisk at the end.

Comment: @FrontEnd I edited my answer again :)

Comment: ok that last edit is what worked. thank you Kartagis

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* Remove the "your name" elements for authenticated users */
function YOURTHEME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
if ($form['is_anonymous']['#value'] == false) {
$form['author']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['comment_body']['und']['0']['#title'] = FALSE; //Remove the user name
$form['comment_body']['und']['0']['#title'] = FALSE;
$form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
 }
}
```

Comment: If it provides an answer to the question. please add some description to your answer